# Calling a string as a function using eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I wish to call append function for a list with append passed in as a string. For instance:

```
List = [1,2]
func = 'append'
value = 3
# I wish to call List.append(value)
```

I know there is a way using `eval` but, I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: `if func == 'append': List.append(value)` ?

Comment: Austin had it, but I also suggest rethinking the process. The `eval` you want can be done by `eval( "List." + func + "(value)" )`, but this is extremely dangerous and highly unrecommended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `getattr`.

```py
List = [1,2]
func = 'append'
value = 3

f = getattr(List, func)
f(value)
print(List)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2]
>>> func = 'append'
>>> value = 3
>>> getattr(my_list, func)(value)
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3]
```